# Google Admob Sdk 6.0.0 "not found for architecture arm64" error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, admob

Xcode Error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GADURequestInterstitial", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m77D58C1021B0E1A9320F3326857B18C58380315E in GoogleMobileAds.iOS.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m77D58C1021B0E1A9320F3326857B18C58380315E)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '7.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '7.11.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.2'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

I using Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v6.0.0

I started facing this issue after installing firebase plugin in game and installing admob latest version

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Build settings inside Unity, I believe that the arm64 can be wrongfully assigned in some environments. Additionally, reimporting the modules and their dependencies again can resolve if something is missing.

Comment: this problem occurs while ios build

Comment: Are you also building for Android?

Comment: yes i am getting builds for both android and ios

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some issues regarding Unity and EDM4U adding `use_frameworks!` by default. Try removing that line and see if it links successfully. If it does, uncheck the use_frameworks! option in EDM4U's settings under Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> iOS Settings